# Why won't this short script work? Need to take a value from input field and append it to div.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var wifi;
                var firewall;
                var backup;
                var vpn; 
                var install; 

                $('submit').click(function(){
                    wifi = $('input[name=wifiPrice]').val(); 
                    firewall = $('input[name=firewallPrice]').val(); 
                    backup = $('input[name=backupPrice]').val(); 
                    vpn = $('input[name=vpnPrice]').val(); 
                    install = $('input[name=installPrice]').val(); 

                    $('list').append('<p>' + wifi + '</p>');  
                });
            }); 
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="cccontainer">
            <form id="costComparer" name="pricesForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" id="wifi">Wifi:</td><td><input type="text" name="wifiPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td class="label" id="firewall">Firewall:</td><td><input type="text" name="fireWallPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" id="backup">Backup:</td><td><input type="text" name="pBackupPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td class="label" id="vpn">VPN:</td><td><input type="text" name="vpnPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label" id="install">Installation:</td><td><input type="text" name="installPrice"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td><input type="button" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </form>

            <div id="list"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am attempting to take in the value of the `wifiPrice` input field, and appending this in a

container into `<div id="list">`. However, it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Could someone point out where I am going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('submit')
```

You don't have a submit element?

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" />
```

would be

```
 $('input[type="button"][value="Submit"]')
```

nor do you have a list element, `$('list')` should be `$('#list')`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DQBJn/)

Comment: Oh I see. I just changed the button and forgot to give it its ID. So can I just have `<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />`, and change `$('submit')` to `$('#submit')`?

Comment: @ByronS - yes you can, ID's are generally the fastest and easiest way to reference an element, see the fiddle, that's exactly what I did there.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. However, for some reason, when i save my file and open it in chrome, it still does not work. I've even tried copying the code directly from the fiddle and it still doesn't work. Does chrome have an issue I need to address with scripts?

Comment: Are you running this on an actual server, like [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), or just opening the file in the browser. If it's the latter, you need to write `https://ajax.googleapis...` when including jQuery, as the shorthand `//` only works on a proper webserver.

Comment: Thank you once again for solving my numerous problems. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

You're not referencing the `div` or the submit button correctly.

Change:

```
$('list').append('<p>' + wifi + '</p>');
```

To

```
$('#list').append('<p>' + wifi + '</p>');
```

Also, you have a problem with the way you attach the click listener.  You need to either assign the button a class or id and then reference it accordingly.  Alternatively you can reference it the way you reference your input fields.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector. You're attaching an handler to an element (a tag) that should be called submit that doesn't exist! It's like you are selecting an element like:

```
<submit>...</submit>
```

So, turn this:

```
$('submit')
```

into this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]')
```